# Should I have reported my Maternity Leave on my CV?

Tags: job-change

I have joined as fresher in a company and have been working with the same company for 3 years.

However, I was on maternity leave for the last one year.

I was looking for a job change and now I am having an offer from a reputed company. The problem is, any basic details check will reveal that I have been on leave for that financial year since the company has paid for 3 months that is during the maternity leave period.

But in the resume I showed them that I was working for the 3 years, and didn't mention the leave period.

Will that be a problem if I accept the offer from the new company? Will they come to know during the background verification and will it put my job at risk?

I have been back at work for 7 months after my maternity leave.

Comment: What country is this in? In the UK you are still employed by a company while on any form of leave and I don't believe a company would omit a maternity period from your employment dates in a reference.

Comment: I've edited the question (which is quite good) to make it a bit more readable, but I agree with @Dustybin80 that your local employment laws are really relevant in this case, so knowing what country/state you're from would help with answers.

Comment: As I understand it, "form 16" is an Indian salary income tax form but I'm not sure how this is relevant. Surely you'll have a relieving letter proving that you're still employed? Were you asked to provide your tax forms when applying or is this a standard practice to determine previous salary?

Comment: @honey: It seems you're new to this site. Welcome! Hopefully it will be a good place for you to find help. That said, I voted to close as it seems this is dependent on your location. While there are hints that you're in India, we need you to make that explicit. Please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/58266/edit) the question, adding appropriate tags or statements to clarify things.

Comment: There is a question here about unpaid leave on the CV http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33220/how-to-denote-unpaid-leave-on-cv
However, this question is about unpaid maternity leave, so I'm not sure if that suggestion makes sense here. Remove the details about "form 16" and then vote to reopen (it's not company/locale specific enough).

Comment: @Lilienthal I assume the idea is that the tax documents will act as a de-facto background check, when you supply your P45-equivalent from one job to the next.

Comment: @Brandin I've removed the reference to form 16 replacing it with the underlying concern of "background check"; but I think this goes beyond company-specific, we answer tons of questions which could *only* apply in the US (e.g. anything to do with Maternity leave varies wildly by country).

Answer (score 8):

Given that this has to do with Indian Conditions, let me answer that from the Indian HR perspective.

You say that you have been working for 3 years, out of which you were on Maternity paid leave for 3 months, and unpaid maternity leave for 9 months (as per my understanding).

In this case, the difference between 2 years of experience and 3 years of experience is **substantial**.

So you should definitely mention this somewhere in your CV, as well as the forms you fill up stating your exact working experience, and not only your employment period.

Comment: How would you recommend notating this? For example, I would imagine in this situation you would just write on your CV "Company ABC, Position, Nov 2012 - Present". The fact that there is time off for maternity leave may technically affect your evaluation of the experience, but how exactly to show this?

Comment: There are many ways of in-directly indicating this. Once could put in a summary like: "A Java developer with 2 years experience", or besides the skills mentioned in the CV, they could put in the duration. And in Large companies candidates often have to fill in a detailed questionnaire, where they have to put in the duration with that skills in months; and most importantly, this fact should be disclosed to the HR during the interview process

Comment: From an outside experience, I would just put employment history ("Employed 2012-2015"), not use the word "experience", and let them ask the question if they think it's relevant. If your only judgement of my competence is how long I've been present in the building, you are ill-equipped to judge my competence; I am fully capable of being bloody useless for 3 years, but present at all times. Ask my wife for confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell (without being a lawyer), you're still employed.

Analogy: if you take 3 weeks of vacation leave, you don't have to write it down in your CV as a period in which you aren't working. Likewise, I don't see any reason why you would need to specify that you were on maternity leave.

Comment: The analogy is a poor one, as a 3 week vacation is not even in the same realm as a 1 year absence, no matter what it's for.  Sure they still technically worked for the company and were employed, but that's quite a bit misleading to say you have 3 years experience in a field, when really you only have 2, even if you've worked for the company for 3 years.

Comment: You're right; conceded.

Comment: Saying one has been employed by ABC Corp from 2012 to 2015 is not the same as claiming 3 years experience. It will depend what she has claimed.